# How to use a custom hook

Tags: php, hooks

I try to create and run a custom hook on my Wordpress site.

In the header.php file I used

```
do_action('somestuff');
```

On my home.php and page.php I does the add_action like

```
add_action('somestuff', 'testfunc');

function testfunc(){
    echo 'hello';
}
```

But the text is not showing? What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your `add_action()` and `add_filter()` should be in the themes `functions.php` file ( or in a plugin ). Trying to add them inside the template file is too late.

Comment: Is there no solution to trigger / callback a function in a template file?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the order of execution. **The order things run matters.**

For your code to function, it would require either `add_action` to implement time travel several microseconds into the past so that it can add the hook before it ran, or it would require `do_action` to implement precognition so that it knows about `add_action` calls in the future that have not happened yet.

By putting your `add_action` call in `home.php` or other templates that occur *after* the `header.php` runs, you are telling WordPress to execute code when a hook fires that has already fired.

It is the equivalent to arriving at an airport and trying to board a flight that has already left.

You need to add the actions *before* the action runs.

A useful mental model is to think of actions as events. When you specify `add_action` of `add_filter` it is the same as saying *"from now on, when this action runs, do this"*.

This is also why you do not see themes add filters and actions inside template files. These go in plugins and `functions.php` because those files are loaded earlier.

Answer (score 0):

As Howdy_McGee and Tom J Nowell noted the issue is in which order actions fire and things happen in WordPress.

You can definitely have custom actions in your template files,

```
// header.php
do_action('my_custom_action');
```

To target these actions, you should add their callbacks to your `functions.php` file. You can use [the conditional helper functions](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/conditional-tags/) to check the context, if you need to run callbacks only on certain templates. Here's couple of examples,

```
// Do something on every template/view
add_action('my_custom_action', 'my_global_header_function');

// conditional checks directly in the callback
add_action('my_custom_action', 'my_custom_action_callback');
function my_custom_action_callback() {

    // Blog page specific
    if ( is_home() ) {
        my_blog_header_function();
    }

    // Only pages
    if ( is_page() ) {
        my_page_header_function();
    }
}

// conditional checks on earlier action
// more typical way to do this in my experience
add_action('template_redirect', 'my_template_redirect_callback');
function my_template_redirect_callback() {
    // Do something on every template/view
    add_action('my_custom_action', 'my_global_header_function');

    // Blog specific function
    if ( is_home() ) {
        add_action('my_custom_action', 'my_blog_header_function');
    }

    // Only pages
    if ( is_page() ) {
        add_action('my_custom_action', 'my_page_header_function');
    }
}

function my_global_header_function() {
    echo 'This works everywhere';
}

function my_blog_header_function() {
    echo 'This the blog page';
}

function my_page_header_function() {
    echo 'This is a page';
}
```

---

*P.S. there's a nice reference list of the different actions WordPress fires by default on the Codex, [Action Reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference).*